# opencv question enough values to unpack (expected 3,got 2)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am unable to understand following error in OpenCV.
I see some stack overflow solutions but I didn't get exact resolution please help me.

This is my error in my terminal.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capture.py", line 25, in <module>
    fs.capture(frame, arg.debug)
  File "D:\Intership\shape-detection-master\filled_shape\filled_shape.py", line 51, in capture
    threshold, contours = img_object.preprocessing_image()
  File "D:\Intership\shape-detection-master\filled_shape\filled_shape.py", line 45, in preprocessing_image
    _,img_contour, contours= cv.findContours(threshold,cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback`

Here are my Following files which you want to look at it:
https://gist.github.com/jyothiprakash097/5574051581afbed912c668efae6e9be3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.findContours` returns `3` objects in `opencv 3.x`, while `2` objects in `opencv 4.x` version.

So, change

`_,img_contour, contours = cv.findContours(threshold,cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

to `contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(threshold,cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` inside `preprocessing_image` function.